# How to use variables outside page.open in PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

What I want to do is to access some variables outside `page.open`, but it doesn't seem to work.

Let's take this piece of code:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var url = 'http://www.bing.com';

var Tester;

page.open(url, function(status) {
    var cont = page.content;
    var patt = /Bing/;
    Tester = patt.test(cont);

    console.log ("Inside " + Tester);

    phantom.exit();
});

console.log ("Outside " + Tester);
```

The output is:

```
Outside undefined
Inside true
```

I would expect both values to be true, and the order to be Inside first and Outside after.
What is going on?

It seems that the code outside is executed before the code inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behavior because `page.open` is asynchronous. It means that as soon as `page.open` is called it will open the specified URL. This will take some time and the next statement (`console.log ("Outside " + Tester);`) is executed before the page is loaded and the `page.open` callback is executed.

This is normal JavaScript behavior with asynchronous functions. If you want to use `Tester` on the outside, you need to let it wait a little until the page is loaded and the callback is executed.

For example like this with a static timeout of 3 seconds and hope that the page is loaded in that time:

```
page.open(...);
setTimeout(function(){
    console.log ("Outside " + Tester);
}, 3000);
```

You can increase the timeout so that you are on the safe side.

The other possibility is to use [`waitFor` from the examples](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/waitfor.js) and explicitly wait for `Tester` to be set:

```
page.open(...);
waitFor(function testFx(){
    return Tester;
}, function onReady(){
    console.log ("Outside " + Tester);
}, 10000); // something big, if it's ready earlier, then it is executed earlier
```